# How to create panel tile in jsp?

Tags: jsp, html-table, panel

I want this like result in jsp:

[image]

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <s:url id="year_url" action="yearcmbact" /> 
            <sj:select  name="set_year" id="set_year" 
                list="yearMap" headerValue="Select year"
                headerKey="1" href="%{year_url}"
                cssStyle="width:95px; height:23px"
                onChangeTopics="reloadyear1_url" onCompleteTopics="reloadyear1_url"
                reloadTopics="reloadyear_url" 
                >
            </sj:select>
            <s:url id="year1_url" action="yearcmbact" /> 
            <sj:select  name="set_year1" id="set_year1" 
                list="yearMap" headerValue="Select year"
                headerKey="1" href="%{year1_url}"
                cssStyle="width:95px; height:23px"
                onChangeTopics="reloadmon_url" onCompleteTopics="reloadmon_url"
                reloadTopics="reloadyear1_url" 
                >
            </sj:select>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I want to show panel with tile in jsp table? any body know please help me....

Comment: @طاهر my problem is show combo box only i want to show tiled panel like box and text

Answer (score 1):

You must use a `<fieldset>` tag:

```
<fieldset>
  <legend>YEAR</legend>

<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <s:url id="year_url" action="yearcmbact" /> 
            <select  name="set_year" id="set_year" 
                list="yearMap" headerValue="Select year"
                headerKey="1" href="%{year_url}"
                cssStyle="width:95px; height:23px"
                onChangeTopics="reloadyear1_url" onCompleteTopics="reloadyear1_url"
                reloadTopics="reloadyear_url" 
                >
            </select>
            <s:url id="year1_url" action="yearcmbact" /> 
            <select  name="set_year1" id="set_year1" 
                list="yearMap" headerValue="Select year"
                headerKey="1" href="%{year1_url}"
                cssStyle="width:95px; height:23px"
                onChangeTopics="reloadmon_url" onCompleteTopics="reloadmon_url"
                reloadTopics="reloadyear1_url" 
                >
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</fieldset>
```

UPDATE :
to blend border corners you need to add this css :

```
fieldset {   
  -moz-border-radius:5px;  
  border-radius: 5px;  
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
}
```

see updated [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Anaxn/2/)